# Can't install iCloud 4 on Dell Inspiron, Win 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, dell-inspiron, icloud

I'm trying to install iCloud 4 on a Dell Inspiron running Windows 7 which is currently has a perfectly running version of iCloud 3.2 installed.

When I try to install from the `Apple Updater`, I get a message that the installation couldn't be completed because a program used in the installation has terminated in an unexpected manner.

When I downloaded the iCloud 4 installation program from the web and tried to install that, the process seemed to go smoothly until the end. Then, I got a message that the installation package was corrupted, and all the changes it had reported making were rolled back.

Comment: You're not the only one - I've been fighting that for 2 weeks on 3 machines, with no joy - even after a repair install.  See http://www.google.com/search?q=icloud+4+install+error+windows to see how many others are struggling too.

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit rough with it, on a spare computer rather than my main machine, in case I really broke something...
After having unsuccessfully tried to compress the contents of the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services folder & failing,
I trashed the whole folder, had IOBit Uninstaller v4 remove as much as it could, then ran the iCloud64.msi from the download location.

This, of course, errored with "Account already exists" & backed out the install.
Why would it be so simple?

Having no option any more to logout, as I'd completely broken iCloud 3 by my fumblings, I tried the iCloud64.msi again... this time I ended the process from Task Manager at the error, instead of letting it roll back - joy & tribulation - it worked.