# Cannot repair or remove iCloud

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, icloud, microsoft-office-2016

Cannot repair or remove iCloud from a Windows 10 Pro PC.

Error code 2343 as shown below.

I cannot find much help on the web!

Trying to tick the Outlook component of the iCloud agent also produces error message "iCloud for Windows Installer Error".

Running Office 2016.

[image: Error code 2343]

Comment: I once managed to brute-force it - see http://superuser.com/questions/821182/cant-install-icloud-4-on-dell-inspiron-win-7/836186#836186

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes such an error with uninstalling, installing or repairing software is caused by redundant concurrent processes. If you have not already tried, you might want to try to boot in a safe mode and then repeat the procedure you have been describing above.
More information on how to boot in a safe mood on Windows 10 can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).
Being in a safe mode you can also try to `run->regedit` and delete everything connected with not needed anymore piece of software, just to make sure that there is nothing left.